# Fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install Fatal server error: no screens found

Tags: graphics, system-installation

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my UEFI ASUS laptop.  Upon my first boot I am presented with a terminal instead of the GUI.  I get a no screens found error if attempting to use startx. I am using an AMD Radeon HD 7730M with a Radeon HD 7660G switchable graphics configuration.  How do I fix no screens error?  
  
 I have followed the instructions on this page [How to turn off ATI Radeon HD 7730M (on Dell inspiron 7520)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192381/how-to-turn-off-ati-radeon-hd-7730m-on-dell-inspiron-7520)  in order to load the driver for my GPU and have the same result.  
  
  After completing installation I attempt to verify using the following command:  
  
  fglrxinfo  
  
  I get Error: unable to open display (null).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What have you tried? Using the search I find a lot of relevant questions. For example, does the following help you? [Why my live installation results blank screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234980/why-my-live-installation-results-blank-screen) (also Asus/UEFI)

Comment: Problem solved:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReyT56rTWnA

Comment: @Ryan Please add your solution as an answer so that others may benefit from your experience!

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and issue the command:

`sudo lspci|grep VGA`

write down the first entries address xx:xx.x on the left (where xx:xx.x is the numbers displayed)

then issue the commands

`sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak` (to back up your current config)

`sudo nvidia-xconfig`

`sudo gedit /det/X11/xorg.conf` (to edit configuration)

Move down to the Device section.

Just before the end section add `BusID "PCI:XX:XX.X"` Where XX:XX.X is your cards address you wrote down earlier.

Save the file, exit and reboot

Source: Ryan solution from comments with minor mods for backup and clarity